# What are the qualities / skills should an User Interface (UI) designer possess?

Tags: javascript, career-development, jquery

**1. What are the qualities / skills  should an User Interface (UI) designer possess?**

**2. Please let me know the weightage (Out of 100%) of having Javascript and Jquery skills in UI designer?**

**Example:** If UI is 100%,

Javascript weightage : 15%

Jquery weightage : 25%

Comment: I wish I could answer, but they closed the question.  I think, for many web applications, that knowledge of how it is built directly helps with designing it. Therefore, I give extra points to people who know how to build their own site.  I'd say more, but this box is too tiny.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your question makes a lot of sense (I'm sorry). UX is platform independant; you can design the UX of a chair, of a TV remote, for a POS terminal, as well as for a website. Even with website design, there are dozens of technologies that can be used to build the interaction of the site.

You need to be familiar with the capabilities of the technology you are using. That's it. The more familiar you are with your technology (whatever it may be), the better you will be able to design your interface around the trade-offs inherent to your platform.

You can't 'quantify' this kind of knowledge into some arbitrary percentage. You need to understand the technical limitations in order to be a good designer. The more knowledgeable about the capabilities of your technology you are, the better a designer you will be. But whether that technology is jQuery, Java, or plastic injection molding (for designing a TV remote) really is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the qualities / skills should an User Interface (UI) designer possess?

They should be good at graphic design. In addition, skills at interaction design, presentation layer development, user experience, copywriting, human factors studies, information architecture, computer science, all help.

> of having Javascript and Jquery skills in UI designer?

There is no 'magic percentage' answer. A good UI designer is only going to be that much better at what they do if they also know how to build said UI, of course.